# Auto sync Design view with Source view in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to auto sync the Design view with the Source view instead of having to hit Ctrl+S or clicking the yellow bar after each change?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing automated as of VS 2008